# displaying specific session variables

Tags: session, variables

I have this simple session, and was trying to get it to display specific session variables to the screen. have not been able to find anything on the web that has been helpful

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

// makes an array 
$colors=array('red', 'yellow', 'blue'); 
// adds it to our session 
$_SESSION['color']=$colors; 
$_SESSION['size']='small'; 
$_SESSION['shape']='round'; 
print "Done";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $var) {
  echo "\$key = \$var<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: This is to display all variables correct? I am looking to display like a single variable from the table. And able to define what variable i want to display